# Не показывается флэшка в IE (во всех версиях)

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, javascript

Есть сайт `tegola.pirogov.ru` флэшка. Она категорически отказывается показываться во всех версиях ИЕ. Флэшка находиться под меню. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: IE7 - все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не показывается?  Все прекрасно показывается. У меня IE восьмой версии. А на чем вы тестируете Ваш сайт?

[image: снимок]

Comment: 9 ИЕ и ИЕ табс для мозилы

Comment: Да что Вы голову ломаете нарисуйте просто гифку и все.

Comment: Нельзя, нужна именно флэха.

Comment: Не беспокойтесь то, что она не работает на вашем локальном компьютере, работает в Интернете, ведь и у ling работает и меня на всех 5 компьютерах ещё и у друзей моих.

Answer (score 0):

IE 9 (9.0.8112.16421 x86) - все отлично!